# Custom ASP.NET Core Identity Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm customizing entities of ASP.NET Core Identity but I ran into this error at runtime:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 
'Kento.Models.ApplicationUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates
the constraint of type 'TUser'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Generic 
Arguments[0], 'Kento.Models.ApplicationUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore
.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,
TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the
constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
```

Here's the list of custom entities:

**DbContext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    <ApplicationUser, 
    ApplicationRole, 
    string, 
    ApplicationUserClaim, 
    ApplicationUserRole, 
    ApplicationUserLogin, 
    ApplicationRoleClaim, 
    ApplicationUserToken>
```

**ApplicationUser:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
     <string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin>
```

**ApplicationRole:**

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    <string, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationRoleClaim>
```

**ApplicationUserClaim:**

```
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
```

**ApplicationUserLogin**

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
```

**ApplicationRoleClaim**

```
public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
```

**ApplicationUserToken**

```
public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
```

I'm so confused what's happening here.

Comment: According to the error, Your `ApplicationUser` class isn't implementing at least one of the generic constraints implemented on the `TUser` type. Take a look at the implementation of the `UserStore` class to see what else they're looking for.

Comment: Having it same issue. Was about implementing UserStore?